# is Firebase push().key length always 20 characters?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to generate a unique key using `.push().key`
Each instance I have seen is exactly 20 characters. Are they always 20 characters? As I plan on adding string length to my firebase rules.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using push(), the generated keys have a fixed length of 20 characters.
See this blog post for more information regarding the generation of the keys.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html